# is using stripslashes() in wordpress unsafe?

Tags: php, wordpress, security

when I create an input

```
<input type="text" name="456" value="123">
```

and pass that data to another php site, Wordpress automatically adds backslashes like:

```
\"my text\"
```

But I need the text in that following way:

```
"my text".
```

And that is why I use the function before i further process the data:

```
stripslashes()
```

Is that an unsafe solution against hacking? It is crucial to know since I send passwords over an API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that this is not WordPress but your installation of PHP having magic quotes enabled.  You should modify your php.ini to disable magic quotes.  Magic Quotes are EVIL!

http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php

Magic Quotes are DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3 and they are completely removed from PHP 5.4.

**UPDATE**
I've never heard of stripslashes being compromised. It's a string on the way in, it'll be a string with less slashes on the way out.  So, if you can't turn off magic quotes, then I would use stripslashes to remove the quotes from the $_POST, etc.  If you're worried about other plugins being affected by your removal of slashes (though I would be surprised), then you could do something like this:

```
class Http {
    private $_instance;
    private $_post;
    private $_get;
    private $_cookie;
    private $_request;

    //singleton pattern to avoid parsing multiple times.
    public static function instance() {
        if( is_null($this->_instance) ) {
            $this->_instance = new self();
        }
        return $this->_instance;
    }
    private function __construct() {
        $isMagicQuotesOn    = get_magic_quotes_gpc();

        $this->_post        = $isMagicQuotesOn ? array_map( array($this,'removeMagic'), $_POST )    : $_POST;
        $this->_get         = $isMagicQuotesOn ? array_map( array($this,'removeMagic'), $_GET )     : $_GET);
        $this->_cookie      = $isMagicQuotesOn ? array_map( array($this,'removeMagic'), $_COOKIE )  : $_COOKIE;
        $this->_request     = $isMagicQuotesOn ? array_map( array($this,'removeMagic'), $_REQUEST ) : $_REQUEST;
    }
    public function removeMagic( $value ) {
        return is_array($value) ? array_map(array($this,'removeMagic'), $value) : stripslashes($value);
    }

    public function get( $var ) {
        return isset($this->_get[$var]) ? $this->_get[$var] : null;
    }
    public function post( $var ) {
        return isset($this->_post[$var]) ? $this->_post[$var] : null;
    }
    public function cookie( $var ) {
        return isset($this->_cookie[$var]) ? $this->_cookie[$var] : null;
    }
    public function request( $var ) {
        return isset($this->_request[$var]) ? $this->_request[$var] : null;
    }
}
```

Then, you can access your vars as: `Http::instance()->get('myvar');`.  Once you do this, then you just need to properly sanitize the input before you do SQL operations, mail() headers, etc., which is where injections would likely occur.  For the DB, you should use something like mysql_real_escape_string (legacy) or Pdo::quote() (currently)...**or better yet, only use prepared statements**. These methods take the DB context and properly sanitize the data for THAT DB, which is much safer than addslashes for the same thing.

Personally, I would rather disable magic quotes.  But if you can't do that, this approach should work.

Comment: WordPress mimics magic quotes for backwards-compatability, even when it's disabled in PHP -- http://codex.wordpress.org/stripslashes_deep#Notes

Answer (score 5):

For future readers, the previous answers are straight-up **wrong**. As per [Ian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/450127/ian-dunn)'s comment, WordPress enforces the equivalent of magic quotes internally to ensure consistent input, backwards compatibility, and to protect newbies from compromising WP installs. It's a hangover from the bad old days™ when it was quite common for people to insert data directly into the database without any sanitising/validation, then write hacky workarounds only for the issues they witnessed rather than doing it properly.

It *is* safe to use `stripslashes()` and `stripslashes_deep()` on your data, as long as you're correctly passing any unescaped data through `$wpdb->insert()`, `$wpdb->prepare()`, etc. when saving it to the database. **Never** write unescaped data to the superglobals like `$_POST` which are expected to remain escaped, use a copy like `$my_post = stripslashes_deep($_POST);`. It is mostly expected that you will do unescaping yourself, which is why it used to be common to see a lot of backslashes littering WP content.

This is completely separate to escaping for html output which should *always* be done on untrusted user input.

Comment: What a relief to see someone chiming in with the correct answer!  WordPress enforces addslashes() even if magic quotes is not on.  Hence if your form field contains quotes you'll need to run stripslashes before saving the data -- NOTE always save via wpdb as someone else has already mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

It should be safe.

According to http://fearlessflyer.com/getting-rid-of-unwanted-backslashes-in-wordpress-form-input/

> According to PHP.net: Magic Quotes are deprecated as of version 5.3 and will not be part of future versions.

See: http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php

Quick answer
Add this to your PHP:

```
<?php 
if ( get_magic_quotes_gpc() ) {
    $_POST      = array_map( 'stripslashes_deep', $_POST );
    $_GET       = array_map( 'stripslashes_deep', $_GET );
    $_COOKIE    = array_map( 'stripslashes_deep', $_COOKIE );
    $_REQUEST   = array_map( 'stripslashes_deep', $_REQUEST );
}
?>
```

Comment: Actually, some plugins may rely on these magic quotes. Removing them in bulk may make you vulnerable to some sort of vulnerabilities like SQL injections.

Comment: @Gumbo, No Plugin for WordPress written by a programmer that you would trust to write a plugin would rely on system-specific magic quotes. Almost all the magic quotes code I've ever seen is to check if it's on and then remove them so that your plugin is portable...no program should ever rely on them being there...that is a HUGE security risk.

Comment: @KevinNelson Even [WordPress itself uses `addslashes`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/search?utf8=✓&q=addslashes&type=Code) for a couple of times.

Comment: @Gumbo, the problem is not addslashes...when you run the addslashes yourself, it's GREAT. You know exactly what's happening and it's portable. When you rely on a system-specific magic-quotes configuration to be enabled in a distributed application, then you've created a security problem. That's why magic quotes was deprecated...it encourages bad programming.

Comment: @KevinNelson : What do you think about the solution to use stripslashes($_POST['XYZ']); whenever I catch $_POST['XYZ'] on a php site and need the variable without slashes. 
Do you think this is safe or is it possible that someone sends some malicious code using my variable $_POST['XYZ'] and stripslashes() actually brings this malicious code to life.

Comment: @BenSpi, I've updated my own answer, since my comment would have been too long.  But, yes, stripslashes should be safe.

Comment: Don't do this, [it *will* break stuff](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/stripslashes_deep#Notes).